# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.hub'

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am using the following packages in my project:

```
boto3==1.20.19
flashtorch==0.1.3
matplotlib==3.3.4
numpy==1.13.3
Pillow==8.4.0
scikit_learn==1.0.1
scipy==1.5.4
seaborn==0.11.2
torch==1.10.0
torchvision==0.11.1
```

When I try to execute the following dependencies:

```
import seaborn as sns
import copy
import boto3
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
import random
import csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import copy
import time
import numpy as np
import os
import pickle
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
import torchvision.models as models
from torch.utils import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from flashtorch.saliency import Backprop
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

def split_train_test(test_size=0.1):

    # Make partition directory.
    print("make partition directory if not exists")
    partition_p = os.path.join("..", "data", "partition")
    if not os.path.exists(partition_p):
        os.mkdir(partition_p)

    # List all input filenames and shuffle.
    base_p = os.path.join("..", "data", "imgs")
    img_ps = []  # e.g. ../data/imgs/MINT/foo.jpg.

    for dir_name in os.listdir(base_p):

        dir_p = os.path.join(base_p, dir_name)
        for img_fname in os.listdir(dir_p):
            img_p = os.path.join(dir_name, img_fname)
            img_ps.append(img_p)
    random.shuffle(img_ps)

    # Keep only baseball cards in MINT or POOR condition, for now.
    print("Keep only baseball cards, for now")
    baseball_sport = "185223"
    img_ps = [p for p in img_ps if baseball_sport in p]

    # Keep only desired conditions.
    print("Exclude good and fair cards to create a 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 scale")
    img_ps = [p for p in img_ps if "GOOD" not in p and "FAIR" not in p]

    # Remove "bad" images.
    # Try to load each image, and only retain it if we can load it
    # successfully as a (255, 255, 3) image.
    print("remove 'bad' images")
    old_img_ps = copy.copy(img_ps)
    img_ps = []
    counter = 0
    for p in old_img_ps:

        try:

            # counter.
            counter += 1
            if counter % 100 == 0:
                print(counter)

            # validate image.
            full_p = os.path.join("..", "data", "imgs", p)
            img = Image.open(full_p)
            img = np.array(img)
            assert img.shape[2] == 3

            # add image to paths.
            img_ps.append(p)

        except Exception as e:

            print("Skip bad image {}".format(p))
            print(e)

    # Train/test split.
    print("split train, test")
    train_ps, test_ps = train_test_split(img_ps, test_size=test_size)

    # Create partition dictionary.
    print("create partition object")
    partition = {
        "train": train_ps,
        "test": test_ps
    }

    # Pickle partition object.
    of_p = os.path.join(partition_p, "partition.p")
    with open(of_p, "wb") as of:
        pickle.dump(partition, of)
    print("wrote {}".format(of_p))


    # Map all unique labels to integer IDs.
    # lbl_to_idx is a dictinary mapping e.g. "EX" -> 0, etc.
    # str_labels = ["MINT", "NM", "EX", "VG", "GOOD", "FAIR", "POOR"]
    str_labels = ["MINT", "NM", "EX", "VG", "POOR"]
    lbl_to_idx = {lbl: i for i, lbl in enumerate(str_labels)}

    # Create labels dictionary.
    # fname_to_lbl is a dictionary mapping e.g. "some_fname.npy" -> 2
    # Example filename.100097_sport185226_conditionVG_preprocessed.npy
    fname_to_lbl = {}
    for p in img_ps:
        # Extract label.
        str_lbl = p.split("_")[-1].lstrip("condition").rstrip(".jpg")
        int_lbl = lbl_to_idx[str_lbl]

        # Add to dictionary.
        fname_to_lbl[p] = int_lbl

    # Pickle fname_to_lbl mapping.
    of_p = os.path.join(partition_p, "labels.p")
    with open(of_p, "wb") as of:
        pickle.dump(fname_to_lbl, of)
    print("wrote {}".format(of_p))


class Dataset(data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, apply_rotations=False):
        """
        parameters
        ----------
        list_IDs (str []) file paths.
        labels (str []) target labels.
        apply_rotations (bool) : if True then randomly rotate images.
            NOTE! This should be FALSE for testing data.
        """
        self.labels = labels  # dictionary. key=fname, value=integer lbl.
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs  # list of filenames.
        self.apply_rotations = apply_rotations
        self.rotation_fn = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.RandomAffine(degrees=90, shear=90)
        ])
        # self.rotation_fn = transforms.RandomRotation(90) # torch rotation function.

        # Initialize AWS storage (s3) resource.
        self.s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3")

        # Make ML_images directory and subdirectories.
        conditions = ["MINT", "NM", "EX", "VG", "FAIR", "GOOD", "POOR"]
        base_p = os.path.join("..", "data", "ml_images")
        if not os.path.exists(base_p):
            os.mkdir(base_p)
            for condition in conditions:
                p = os.path.join(base_p, condition)
                os.mkdir(p)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.list_IDs)

    def download_from_s3(self, remote_fname):
        # download fname from s3 as ../data/ml_images/{REMOTE FNAME}
        local_fname = os.path.join("..", "data", "ml_images", remote_fname)
        print("download {}".format(remote_fname))

        # download image from S3 as "img.jpg"
        resp = self.s3_resource.Object(
            "mintcondition",
            remote_fname
        ).download_file(local_fname)

        return None

    def load_and_preprocess_img(self, img_p, apply_rotations=False):
        """ load and preprocess img, optionally applying rotations

        parameters:
        -----------
        img_p (str)  path to image.
        apply_rotations (bool) if True apply rotations to the image.
                                should be false to all testing.

        returns:
        --------
        X  (torch tensor) Image as torch tensor of shape (3, 255, 255)
        """

        # Load image and reshape to (3, 255, 255)
        img = Image.open(img_p)
        img = img.resize((255, 255), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        # optionally rotate.
        if apply_rotations:
            img = self.rotation_fn(img)

        # Cast to torch tensor.
        X = np.array(img)  # (255, 255, 3) numpy
        assert X.shape == (255, 255, 3)
        X = X / 255  # "normalize"
        X = X.swapaxes(1, 2)  # (255, 3, 255)
        X = X.swapaxes(0, 1)  # (3, 255, 255) numpy
        X = torch.from_numpy(X).float()  # (3, 255, 255) torch

        return X

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        try:

            # Select sample.
            remote_p = self.list_IDs[index]

            # Get label.
            y = self.labels[remote_p]

            # If the image does not exist locally, get it from S3.
            local_p = os.path.join("..", "data", "ml_images", remote_p)
            if not os.path.exists(local_p):
                self.download_from_s3(remote_p)

            # Load image and reshape to torch tensor of shape (3, 255, 255)
            X = self.load_and_preprocess_img(local_p, apply_rotations=self.apply_rotations)  # torch tensor.

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("exception loading data..using random image, label instead")
            X = np.random.random((3, 255, 255))
            X = torch.from_numpy(X).float()
            y = 0

        return X, y


def set_parameter_requires_grad(model, feature_extracting):
    if feature_extracting:
        for param in model.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False


def reenable_gradients(model):

    for param in model.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = True


def initialize_model(model_name, num_classes, feature_extract, use_pretrained=True):
    model_ft = None
    input_size = 0

    if model_name == "resnet":
        """ Resnet18
        """
        model_ft = models.resnet18(pretrained=use_pretrained)
        set_parameter_requires_grad(model_ft, feature_extract)
        num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
        model_ft.fc = torch.nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
        input_size = 224

    elif model_name == "alexnet":
        """ Alexnet
        """
        model_ft = models.alexnet(pretrained=use_pretrained)
        set_parameter_requires_grad(model_ft, feature_extract)
        num_ftrs = model_ft.classifier[6].in_features
        model_ft.classifier[6] = torch.nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
        input_size = 224

    elif model_name == "vgg":
        model_ft = models.vgg11_bn(pretrained=use_pretrained)
        set_parameter_requires_grad(model_ft, feature_extract)
        num_ftrs = model_ft.classifier[6].in_features
        model_ft.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
        input_size = 224

    elif model_name == "squeezenet":
        model_ft = models.squeezenet1_0(pretrained=use_pretrained)
        set_parameter_requires_grad(model_ft, feature_extract)
        model_ft.classifier[1] = nn.Conv2d(512, num_classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        model_ft.num_classes = num_classes
        input_size = 224

    elif model_name == "densenet":
        model_ft = models.densenet121(pretrained=use_pretrained)
        set_parameter_requires_grad(model_ft, feature_extract)
        num_ftrs = model_ft.classifier.in_features
        model_ft.classifier = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
        input_size = 224

    elif model_name == "inception":
        """ Inception v3
        Be careful, expects (299,299) sized images and has auxiliary output
        """
        model_ft = models.inception_v3(pretrained=use_pretrained)
        set_parameter_requires_grad(model_ft, feature_extract)
        # Handle the auxilary net
        num_ftrs = model_ft.AuxLogits.fc.in_features
        model_ft.AuxLogits.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
        # Handle the primary net
        num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
        model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
        input_size = 299

    else:
        print("Invalid model name, exiting...")
        exit()

    return model_ft, input_size


def train_model(model, dataloaders, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs=25, is_inception=False, device="cpu"):

    since = time.time()

    val_acc_history = []

    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    best_acc = 0.0

    # Initiailize a file to track accuracy over epochs.
    acc_of_p = os.path.join("..", "data", "model_accuracy.csv")
    acc_of = open(acc_of_p, "w", newline="")
    header = ["epoch", "phase", "accuracy", "F", "r"]
    w = csv.writer(acc_of)
    w.writerow(header)

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epochs - 1))
        print('-' * 10)

        # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
        for phase in ['train', 'test']:
            if phase == 'train':
                model.train()  # Set model to training mode
            else:
                model.eval()  # Set model to evaluate mode

            running_loss = 0.0
            running_corrects = 0.0
            ypreds = []
            ytrues = []

            # Iterate over data.
            batch_num = 0
            for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)

                # zero the parameter gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                # forward
                # track history if only in train
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                    # Get model outputs and calculate loss
                    # Special case for inception because in training it has an auxiliary output. In train
                    #   mode we calculate the loss by summing the final output and the auxiliary output
                    #   but in testing we only consider the final output.
                    if is_inception and phase == 'train':
                        # From https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-optimize-inception-model-with-auxiliary-classifiers/7958
                        outputs, aux_outputs = model(inputs)
                        loss1 = criterion(outputs, labels)
                        loss2 = criterion(aux_outputs, labels)
                        loss = loss1 + 0.4 * loss2
                    else:
                        outputs = model(inputs)
                        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)

                    # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                    if phase == 'train':
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()

                # statistics
                running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
                F = f1_score(preds.numpy(), labels.data.numpy(), average="micro")
                ypreds.extend(list(preds.numpy()))
                ytrues.extend(list(labels.data.numpy()))

                # counter.
                batch_num += 1

                if batch_num % 1 == 0:
                    correct = float(torch.sum(preds == labels.data))
                    incorrect = float(torch.sum(preds != labels.data))
                    perc_correct = 100 * correct / (correct + incorrect)
                    msg = """
                    epoch {} batch {} : percent correct={:.4f} F={:.4f}
                    """.format(epoch, batch_num, perc_correct, F)
                    print(msg)
                    print(preds)
                    print(labels.data)

                    # rank correlation of predicted, actual.
                    rho, p = spearmanr(preds.numpy(), labels.data.numpy())
                    print("correlation of pred, actual: rho = {:.4f}".format(rho))

            epoch_loss = running_loss / len(dataloaders[phase].dataset)
            epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / len(dataloaders[phase].dataset)
            epoch_F = f1_score(ypreds, ytrues, average="micro")
            epoch_R = pearsonr(ypreds, ytrues)[0]

            print('{} Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(phase, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))

            # deep copy the model
            if phase == 'val' and epoch_acc > best_acc:
                best_acc = epoch_acc
                best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
            if phase == 'val':
                val_acc_history.append(epoch_acc)

            # Write latest train and test accuracies to output file.
            out = [epoch, phase, epoch_acc.numpy(), epoch_F, epoch_R]
            w.writerow(out)
            acc_of.flush()

        # Pickle the model after end of epoch.
        of_p = os.path.join("..", "models", "latest_model.p")
        with open(of_p, "wb") as of:
            pickle.dump(model, of)
        print("wrote {}".format(of_p))

    time_elapsed = time.time() - since
    print('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
    print('Best val Acc: {:4f}'.format(best_acc))

    # close output file.
    of.flush()
    of.close()
    print("wrote {}".format(acc_of_p))

    # load best model weights
    model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
    return model, val_acc_history


def train_CNN_model(num_classes=5, load_latest_model=False):

    # Use CUDA if available.
    use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
    print("check if CUDA can be used -> {}".format(use_cuda))
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if use_cuda else "cpu")

    # Define transformations of the images.
    # Note that the normalization transform with these specific
    # Parameters is necessary for working with pretrained AlexNet.
    normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    img_transforms = transforms.Compose([
        normalize
    ])

    # Parameters
    params = {
        "batch_size": 64,
        "shuffle": True,
        "num_workers": 4
    }
    max_epochs = 10

    # Datasets.
    print("load train/test partition and labels")
    partition_p = os.path.join("..", "data", "partition", "partition.p")
    labels_p = os.path.join("..", "data", "partition", "labels.p")

    partition = pickle.load(open(partition_p, "rb"))
    labels = pickle.load(open(labels_p, "rb"))
    print("create generators over train, test data")
    train_set = Dataset(partition["train"], labels, apply_rotations=True)  # do rotate train data.
    train_g = data.DataLoader(train_set, **params)

    test_set = Dataset(partition["test"], labels, apply_rotations=False)  # don't rotate test data.
    test_g = data.DataLoader(test_set, **params)

    if load_latest_model:
        print("load pickled latest_model.p")
        model_p = os.path.join("..", "models", "latest_model.p")
        model = pickle.load(open(model_p, "rb"))
    else:
        model, _ = initialize_model(
            model_name="resnet",  # resnet 18 with skip connections.
            num_classes=num_classes,
            feature_extract=True,  # if True only finetune top layer.
            use_pretrained=True
        )
    model.to(device)

    # Initialize optimizer, loss criterion.
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
    criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    # Train model.
    model, history = train_model(
        model=model,
        dataloaders={"train": train_g, "test": test_g},
        criterion=criterion,
        optimizer=optimizer,
        num_epochs=max_epochs,
        is_inception=False,
        device=device
    )

    # Pickle best performing model.
    of_p = os.path.join("..", "models", "best_model.p")
    with open(of_p, "wb") as of:
        pickle.dump(model, of)
    print("wrote {}".format(of_p))

    # Pickle history of best performing model.
    of_p = os.path.join("..", "models", "history.p")
    with open(of_p, "wb") as of:
        pickle.dump(history, of)
    print("wrote {}".format(of_p))


def load_and_preprocess_img(img_p):

    # Load image and reshape to (3, 255, 255)
    img = Image.open(img_p)
    img = img.resize((255, 255), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # Cast to torch tensor.
    X = np.array(img)  # (255, 255, 3) numpy
    X = X.reshape((1, 255, 255, 3))
    X = X / 255  # "normalize"
    X = X.swapaxes(2, 3)  # (64, 255, 3, 255)
    X = X.swapaxes(1, 2)  # (64, 3, 255, 255) numpy
    X = torch.from_numpy(X).float()  # (64, 3, 255, 255) torch

    return X


def saliency_map(model, img_p):

    # Load and preprocess image.
    X = load_and_preprocess_img(img_p)  # (3, 255, 255 torch tensor)
    X.requires_grad_()  # This is critical to actually get gradients.


    with torch.set_grad_enabled(True):
        backprop = Backprop(model)  # flashtorch.saliency Backprop object.
        gradients = backprop.calculate_gradients(X, take_max=True, guided=False)  # (1, 255, 255)

    # Cast image, saliency maps to numpy arrays.
    X = X.detach()  # must 'detach' from gradients before slicing.
    img_np = X.numpy()[0]  # (3, 255, 255)
    img_np = img_np.swapaxes(0, 1)  # (255, 3, 255)
    img_np = img_np.swapaxes(1, 2)  # (255, 255, 3)
    saliency_map_np = gradients.numpy()[0]  # (255, 255)
    print(max(np.max(saliency_map_np, axis=0)))
    print(saliency_map_np)
    print(img_np.shape)
    print(saliency_map_np.shape)

    # Smooth heatmap.
    saliency_map_np = gaussian_filter(saliency_map_np, sigma=10)

    # Plot image and overlay saliency map.
    heatmap = sns.heatmap(saliency_map_np, alpha=0.5)
    heatmap.imshow(img_np, cmap="YlGnBu")
    plt.show()

    return saliency_map_np


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # split_train_test()
    # train_CNN_model(load_latest_model=False, num_classes=5)

    model_p = os.path.join("..", "models", "cloud_model.p")
    model = pickle.load(open(model_p, "rb"))
    reenable_gradients(model)  # e.g., disable fine-tuning mode
    # img_p = os.path.join("..", "demos", "demo_cards",
    #                    "very_good.jpg")
    img_p = os.path.join("..", "data", "imgs", "POOR",
                         "9078_sport185223_conditionPOOR.jpg")
    sm = saliency_map(model, img_p)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/Desktop/Code/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/_internally_replaced_utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    from torch.hub import load_state_dict_from_url
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.hub'
```

Any suggestions why? What is wrong with my installed packages?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Would be better if you put your code as well. Could you put your code?

Comment: @yakhyo It is basically a script to train a cnn. Please find my code updated.